# How to style LiveChart's CartesianChart AxisX Labels?

Tags: wpf, axis-labels, livecharts

I've searched around the web, but have not found what I'm looking for or even if its possible at all (so far).
I have a cartesian chart and what I would like to do, is style the labels of the AxisX. I've seen how to change it's colour, for instance, by setting the foreground of the Axis, but, what I would like to achieve with this style, is to align the label's content by centering them. Seems pretty basic as setting 'HorizontalContentAlignment' to 'Center', but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Here is an extract of my sample code:

```
        <lc:CartesianChart LegendLocation="Top">
            <lc:CartesianChart.ChartLegend>
                <local:MonthlySummaryCustomLegendView />
            </lc:CartesianChart.ChartLegend>
            <lc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lc:Axis Title="Days of Month"
                         ShowLabels="True"
                         MaxValue="28"
                         MinValue="1">
                    <lc:Axis.Separator>
                        <lc:Separator Step="1" 
                                      IsEnabled="False">
                        </lc:Separator>
                    </lc:Axis.Separator>
                </lc:Axis>
            </lc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lc:CartesianChart>
        (...)
```

And this is a screenshot of how it currently renders:

[image]

Thank you all in advance, any help or guidelines will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean and easy way.

- You can't really differentiate the axis labels via the visual tree:
  [image: Visual Tree]
- You can't access the `TextBlock` property of the `AxisSeparatorElement` without reflection as it's internal

Comment: However, I can see from your screenshot that you achieved it. Could you please, show me how? Just to have a vague idea where to start. I want to at least, try. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the red border? That's from the WPF inspection tool `Snoop`.

Comment: No, what I meant is that on your screenshot your labels appear to be centered (?)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Are you talking about the x or y axis? Could you post a screenshot explaining?

Comment: I'm sorry for all the confusion, I mean the labels on the x axis ('Test', 'b').

Comment: 'b' is not centered or am I missing something? Which type of series are you using? I'm using 4 ColumnSeries in the screenshot and haven't modified the axis labels.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply and once more, for the confusion. I misinterpreted your example chart. At first I was using ColumnSeries as well, but now the requirements have changed and this (centering the label's content) is a customization that is no longer needed. Thank you anyway for your time and help, I'll mark your answer as accepted.